nginx reverse proxy working with ws but not with wss
Lately i wrote an application that uses standard WebSockets to communicate.
Now i wanted to connect to the frontend with using SecureWebSockets (aka wss://...) and SSL.
Therfore i set up a nginx reverse proxy on a linode server.
When i use just the ip as server_name and a standard WebSocket connection (aka  ws://...) in the frontend everything works fine.
As soon as i change the config to use SSL it breaks and i have no idea why.
The config for the standard WebSockets looks something like this:
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name (ip_address);

    access_log /var/log/nginx/backend.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/backend-error.log error;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8111;

        #WebSocket magic
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

The config for the SecureWebSockets looks something like this:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name (custom_domain.com);
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name (custom_domain.com);

    access_log /var/log/nginx/backend.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/backend-error.log error;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8111;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

All relevant ports are set to allow in ufw and i already tested if the cert is correctly working.
The odd thing is that there are no errors in the nginx logs and nothing in the access logs.
I have no idea what i could possibly try to get it working. This is kind of my last resort to get this working.
If anyone has an idea what i could try i would be really glad.
Thanks in advance :)
EDIT:
The problem is, that i don't get any real errors. Neither from frontend nor the backend. I'm trying to provide the best "errors" i can.
I'm trying to access the websocket via react expo:
`client = new WebSocket("wss://custom_domain.com")`

(The backend is written in java and is just a basic WebSocket, that accepts the connection.)
I tried accessing from the frontend hosted locally and from a netlify instance.
When i send from localhost the WS Analysis looks something like this:
(there is literally nothing else (maybe the callstack, but i dont think thats neccessary)
Piture of Chrome WS Analysis
When i send via netlify nothing happens, no "messages" are sent. The connection just fails.
As mentioned above nginx doesn't throw any erros in the log, so i think the request doesn't even reach the server?
(I'm new to WebSockets aswell as StackOverflow, so sorry if my question isn't that percise)
openssl response (openssl s_client -connect yourhost:443) :

    subject=CN=custom_domain.com
    issuer=C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=E6
    ---
    No client certificate CA names sent
    Peer signing digest: SHA256
    Peer signature type: ECDSA
    Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
    ---
    SSL handshake has read 2400 bytes and written 409 bytes
    Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    ---
    New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Protocol: TLSv1.3
    Server public key is 256 bit
    This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
    Compression: NONE
    Expansion: NONE
    No ALPN negotiated
    Early data was not sent
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    ---
    ---
    Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
    SSL-Session:
        Protocol  : TLSv1.3
        Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        Session-ID: 1F6DBE1DE581C1FCC12938F19C71AC54E5AB76F31C3DCBF4C692276C82C2BFBC
        Session-ID-ctx:
        Resumption PSK: 
        PSK identity: None
        PSK identity hint: None
        SRP username: None
        TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 86400 (seconds)
        TLS session ticket:
        0000 - a0 39 f1 9b e5 0a 90 3d-80 24 5b 80 28 f1 3f e6   .9.....=.$[.(.?.
        0010 - 2b 1c c9 39 ef 1e d4 d9-c9 9f 91 ea 4f 5e 0e ce   +..9........O^..
    
        Start Time: 1730061634
        Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
        Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
        Extended master secret: no
        Max Early Data: 0
    ---
    read R BLOCK
    ---
    Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
    SSL-Session:
        Protocol  : TLSv1.3
        Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        Session-ID: 32CD15B2E389CE3526C3A834F8D1A1498160CBDC09987D28E5931E4F4F3BFD20
        Session-ID-ctx:
        Resumption PSK: 
        PSK identity: None
        PSK identity hint: None
        SRP username: None
        TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 86400 (seconds)
        TLS session ticket:
        0000 - 69 37 6d 62 65 3e 73 b1-87 1a 61 9a bb be b0 8c   i7mbe>s...a.....
        0010 - d3 6c df c6 0c f5 e3 d2-4b f9 30 02 84 f5 9b 8e   .l......K.0.....
    
        Start Time: 1730061634
        Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
        Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
        Extended master secret: no
        Max Early Data: 0
    ---
    read R BLOCK
    closed



All what you provide as error description is "does not work". No information on how you actually try to access the websocket, what error messages you get in the browser console for failures etc. This is not sufficient to help you. Please provide the necessary detail by editing your question, not by adding more comments here.

"... and i already tested if the cert is correctly working"  - how did you do that exactly?  Did you actually do a https://... to your domain with exactly the same setting as you show here or what did you make to ensure that the certificate was installed correctly?

@SteffenUllrich no, this sentence was probably formulated a bit poorly by me. i meant i tested the certificate chain with the "openssl" command

I assume that you mean using openssl verify with this - which says nothing about a successful configuration of the certificate in the server nor the reachablity of the server. Please do a openssl s_client -connect yourhost:443 from the the system were you run the browser and include the output of this into your question to narrow down the problem.

@SteffenUllrich Thank you, that was really helpful. It  seems, that it's "unable to get local issuer certificate".

So it seems like your HTTPS setup is not properly configured. Based on your  output you it looks like you send only the leaf certificate of your host, but not the chain certificates. Unfortunately you removed some crititical parts of the output, so I might be wrong here. But you might check your site with SSLLabs

@SteffenUllrich Yeah sorry, i was not quite sure if it was safe to post the whole output, therefore i deleted the upper part. But the SSLLabs evaluation tells me that SSL is working fine and only the http request does not work (HTTP 1.1.). This is probably the root of my issue. Any idea what i could try? (PS: maybe you can tell if it is safe to post the whole output,then i can do that aswell). Kind regards

The part before the server certificate is the interesting one since it shows the full certificate chain sent by the server. But if you got a grade A in SSLLabs (did you?) then the chain should be fine. It really is impossible for me to give you more help then w/o having something reproducible - which would mean the real URL in question.

Using wsdump gives a 502 gateway error, i.e. problems in the communication between nginx and what you gave as proxy_pass This suggests a broken nginx setup, like using plain http in proxy_pass while the internal backend expects https or vice versa. Or the backend not running on this poirt at all. There should be error logs in nginx for this.

@SteffenUllrich yes, thank you a lot. i finally found the error. I messed something up in the backend. Although the bug was on my side in the end you helped me lot to find the error, appreciate that (it will be a lot easier to debug websockets in the future). Cheers :)

Solved with the help of @SteffenUlrich. The problem was an internal error in the backkend.
